# Pandas changing column value based on substring in other column

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas I'm trying to edit a column `Year` in a dataframe by checking column `Age` containing dates such as `Mon Dec 28 11:19:42 CST 2007`.

`ID    Age                            Year`
`1     Mon Dec 28 11:19:42 CST 2007   NaN`
`2     Tue Sep 28 12:39:41 CST 2008   NaN`

I'm trying to do this by using `df.loc[df[df.Age.str.contains("2007")], 'Year'] = 2007`, however, this returns the error `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 20 to array axis with dimension 11359`

Expected result:

`ID    Age                            Year`
`1     Mon Dec 28 11:19:42 CST 2007   2007`
`2     Tue Sep 28 12:39:41 CST 2008   NaN`
`df[df['Age'].str.contains("2007")]['Year'] = 2007` also does not work. Can anyone help me out how I could do this properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `df.loc[df.Age.str.contains("2007"), 'Year'] = 2007`.

Comment: Im a chump. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.Age.str.endswith("2007"), 'Year'] = 2007
print (df)
   ID                           Age    Year
0   1  Mon Dec 28 11:19:42 CST 2007  2007.0
1   2  Tue Sep 28 12:39:41 CST 2008     NaN
```

Or [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df.loc[df.Age.str.contains("2007"), 'Year'] = 2007
print (df)
   ID                           Age    Year
0   1  Mon Dec 28 11:19:42 CST 2007  2007.0
1   2  Tue Sep 28 12:39:41 CST 2008     NaN
```

Another possible solution by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df.Year = df.Year.mask(df.Age.str.endswith("2007"), 2007)
print (df)
   ID                           Age    Year
0   1  Mon Dec 28 11:19:42 CST 2007  2007.0
1   2  Tue Sep 28 12:39:41 CST 2008     NaN
```